# Is any google scholar API available for fetching abstract of publications?

Tags: chatgpt-api, google-scholar

there, is there any google scholar API available for GPT to search/harness abstract of published journal papers?

for question asked by users, the GPT will generate key words, which will be used by google scholar for relevant publications, and the abstracts of these publications will be returned to GPT as the 2ry knowledge source for scientific answer.